# How to change sample text in font installer

Tags: fonts, previews

I have several Japanese fonts but do not want to install them all.  I would like to preview them before installing.

In icon view I can get a very rough idea of the style of the font as it shows Aa.  When I open the font I am presented with a dialog box which shows a sample of the font with the sentence *The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog*.

I would like to change this sample text to Japanese text to get a fuller preview of the font.  Is it at all possible?  I suspect I might have to edit and compile source, not something I'm very familiar with.

Comment: There's a bug report on this you might want to follow: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-font-viewer/+bug/385335 (It dates back to 2009, however)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to the preinstalled font-viewer:

Font Manager allows you to compare fonts with your own custom text.

```
sudo apt install font-manager
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good place to start.  At the moment it seems to have made all the fonts available to Ubuntu, but I may have overlooked a setting at this early stage.

Comment: So is there a way to accomplish this without installing the font? I have 300'000 fonts to look through, and don't want to install them all.

Comment: I think this is no longer true. It seems they have removed this functionality from font manager.

Comment: Actually now you can still do it, but only in the "preview" tab